# theme email-inline.css not being used

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, css, email-templates

I am using Magento 1.9.1. I want to modify email-inline.css with some custom styles for a particular transactional email.  I have created email-inline.css in my theme, but when I preview the email, only the styles in the original email-inline.css are used.  If I create a new file email-inline1.css in the base directory, and refer to it specifically in the email template, it will pick that up, but it seems not to bother looking in my theme folder.  Am I doing something wrong??  I don't want to have to specify all the styles in each email.

Comment: Can you verify that it also does not work in generated emails? Email preview can be wonky in Magento.

Comment: And what about the sourcecode of the email ? Has the email-inline.css the correct path to your custom theme ?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion here is that you are using the preview functionality in the admin section which does not know about your custom theme. I have seen the same problem in the cms preview feature.

What you will need to do is either set the correct them during the preview action.

Comment: my newsletter email showing empty `<style>` tags. While I put `email-inline.css` in every theme folder. need help. Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504461/magento-1-9-style-email-template

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The answer is quite straightforward: I was wrongly using System->Design to assign the theme (this is meant for overriding the theme for a limited amount of time, and apparently doesn't affect emails)  When I correctly used the System->Configuration->General->Design panel, and completed all the Package and Themes entries, the email theme overrides all started working!